# SonarQube: Startup failed Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We have encountered the following error:

```
Startup failed Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM
```

running SonarQube as systemd service under Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenJdk 1.8, on every SonarQube 6.x version.
No problem if we run SonarQube, after the server boot, from shell with the following command:
    systemctl start sonar.service

Comment: This sounds as a security rights issue.

Comment: So after your advice, I have commented out the following line on my systemd script:

   #User=sonar
   #Group=sonar

Answer (score -2):

Try this implementation:

```
export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```